# $\int_{0}^{x_{x>0}} \left(\sin^2(x)\cos(x)\right) \text{d}x=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sin^2(x)\cos(x)\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometry

The original problem is:

> $$\int_{0}^{x_{x>0}} \left(\sin^2(x)\cos(x)\right) \text{d}x=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sin^2(x)\cos(x)\right)$$

With the work I've done I'm only left to this equation:

> $$\frac{\sin^3(x)}{3}=\frac{3\sin(3x)-\sin(x)}{4}$$
>
> ---

My work:

$$\int_{0}^{x_{x>0}} \left(\sin^2(x)\cos(x)\right) \text{d}x=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sin^2(x)\cos(x)\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int_{0}^{x_{x>0}} \left((\sin(x))^2\cos(x)\right) \text{d}x=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sin^2(x)\cos(x)\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

$u=\sin(x) \Longrightarrow \frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}x}=\cos(x) \Longleftrightarrow \text{d}u=\cos(x)\text{d}x$ & $\{_{x=0}^{x=x} \Longrightarrow \{_{u=0}^{u=\sin(x)}$:

---

$$\int_{0}^{\sin(x)} \left(u^2\right) \text{d}u=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sin^2(x)\cos(x)\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left[\frac{1}{3}u^3\right]_{0}^{\sin(x)}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sin^2(x)\cos(x)\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{3}\left[u^3\right]_{0}^{\sin(x)}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sin^2(x)\cos(x)\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{3}\left[\sin^3(x)\right]_{0}^{x}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sin^2(x)\cos(x)\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\sin^3(x)}{3}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sin^2(x)\cos(x)\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\sin^3(x)}{3}=\cos(x)\cdot\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(\sin^2(x))\right)+\sin^2(x)\cdot\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(\cos(x))\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\sin^3(x)}{3}=2\cos^2(x)\sin(x)+\sin^2(x)\cdot\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(\cos(x))\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\sin^3(x)}{3}=2\cos^2(x)\sin(x)-\sin(x)\sin^2(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\sin^3(x)}{3}=\frac{3\sin(3x)-\sin(x)}{4}\Longleftrightarrow$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I may suggest, use $t$ in the integrand and think about the fundamental theorem of calculus. It will be much faster.

Comment: The derivation look correct to me. To finish it off you can use $\sin(3x) = 3\sin(x) - 4\sin^3(x)$ to arrive at $\sin(x)\left[\sin^2(x)-\frac{3}{5}\right] = 0$

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second to last step, instead of introducing $\sin(3x)$, try using the fundamental identity $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$ to get rid of the cosine and have an equation involving just $\sin(x)$ and its powers. Then, if $t=\sin(x)$...